# How to create a bubble in android without a notification for a non chat app?

Tags: android

I'd like to implement a bubble that could have some shortcuts and other functionality for my app.

Searching for this the only thing that comes up is [Notification bubbles for chat apps](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/bubbles)
But this wouldn't be a notification, and certainly wouldn't be linked to a contact (instead most likely to the current foreground app).

[This guide shows how to draw over other apps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/), haven't fully modified it, but seems if I follow this example I'd have to implement the functionality of a bubble myself, like being pulled to the edge of the screen, removing it when hovered over a section of the screen, etc.

Is there a way to leverage the bubbles classes to implement a non-notification non-chat bubble?

Comment: you can create a widget for the same

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to leverage the bubbles classes to implement a non-notification non-chat bubble?

Sorry, no.

> seems if I follow this example I'd have to implement the functionality of a bubble myself, like being pulled to the edge of the screen, removing it when hovered over a section of the screen, etc.

It also will not work on some entry-level Android devices today and requires a permission that users may not want to grant.